# Handle FCM notification In Android Oreo when the App is closed or pause State

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.1-oreo

Here I facing Notification issue in Android Oreo, That is when the FCM sent push notification to the Android Oreo, it will show the notification when the app is run in the foreground ,that is because of the service is running in the background , it can handle additional parameters and its value , but the problem arise when the app is close or paused state , The OS destroy the Service automatically when the app is closed or paused states , in order the handle notification FCM provides High priority Push notification method ,in which the push notification Json has two parts ,one is "data" , and another one is "notification", The data part can handle by the services when the app is running in foreground , but the Notification part manage by Android OS ,  There are  default keys to handle notification for display notification icons ,title,messaged and Priority , With the use of high priority push notification can wake up the app when we hit on the notification ,and access the information by applying bundle with the starting Activity . but the problem is how to put extra data in In notification , when I trying to add additional data in to the "notification" part into the Json ,The OS not displaying notification . So how can I manage this issue .. ?

```
 {
"to" : "e1w6hEbZn-8:APA91bEUIb2JewYCIiApsMu5JfI5Ak...",
"notification": {
    "body": "message",
    "title": "Title",
    "icon": "appicon"
},
"data" : {
    "body": "message",
    "title": "Title",
}}
```

Comment: Try to add an extra parameter in notification object from server side manually. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an extra parameter in notification object from server side manually. It worked for me.

```
 { "to" : "e1w6hEbZn-8:APA91bEUIb2JewYCIiApsMu5JfI5Ak...", 
      "notification": {
        "body": "message",
        "title": "Title",
        "icon": "appicon" ,
        "extra_param":"value"
 }, 
     "data" : {
        "body": "message",
        "title": "Title", 
}
}
```